# My sql Query to format data in a proper manner and export it in csv format

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a mysql command :-
"mysql -uroot -pxxx -e "use dbname; select * from tablename;" | wc -l"
whose ouput is "23" like this i'm having multiple tablename from which i need figures and i want to re-direct those figures in a file like this:

```
 "table1 = 23"
 "table2 = 25"
 "table3 = 45"
```

I tried this sql query:-

```
 SELECT 'table1' AS table_label, COUNT(*) AS table_size FROM table1 
 UNION SELECT 'table2', COUNT(*) FROM table2 
 UNION SELECT 'table3', COUNT(*) FROM table3
```

but it gives me results like this :-

```
 +---------------------+------------+
 | table_label         | table_size |
 +---------------------+------------+
 | 2016-03-17 12:10:14 |        132 |
 | 2016-03-17 12:10:37 |         33 |
 +---------------------+------------+
```

but i want the table to be like this :-

```
 +---------------------+------------+
 | table_label         | table_size |
 +---------------------+------------+
 | table1              |        132 |
 | table2              |         33 |
 +---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: This sounds like suspicious behavior